# brew upgrade <package> is doing a full upgrade instead of just one package

Tags: homebrew

All I wanted was to upgrade deno from 1.x to 1.2x but `brew upgrade deno` is making a full upgrade which has taken 2 hrs and is at `make` now.

My python also has been upgraded to 3.11.

Why can't brew upgrade just deno ?

Comment: What do you mean with "full upgrade"? Does it upgrade any other packages than the ones `deno` depends on?

Comment: https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-does-brew-upgrade-formula-or-brew-install-formula-also-upgrade-a-bunch-of-other-stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deno` has the following dependencies:

- llvm
- ninja
- python@3.11
- rust

If you upgrade `deno`, it will upgrade all dependent packages as well.

If you need your Python to be a specific version, install that version (i.e. `python@3.9`) and set up your PATH with the instructions provided post-install of the other Python version.

Additionally, as has been noted in the comments, Brew does not provide bottles for macOS Mojave. In the case of `rust`, a list can be seen here which shows that Big Sur is the oldest OS with bottled `rust`: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/rust

Comment: My make is after configuring rust@1.66.0 - its been over 30 mins - does it need to take so long ?

Comment: @anjanesh What OS version are you running? I just tried `brew install rust` and it took just a minute or two, including a couple dependencies. It should not need to compile rust to install it...

Comment: Mac Book Pro 15.6" i7 2018 | macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: `==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/rust/1.66.0 --enable-vendor --set rust.jemalloc --release-channel=stable`
<br>
`==> make`

Comment: People think they should be using Homebrew, but don't bother to learn how it works.  Homebrew is not providing bottles for Rust for Mojave.  See https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/rust

Comment: really bad DX, quite surprised to see everyone normalising it. I just installed `watchman` and its been going on for 30 mins, keeps installing tons of dependencies on and on. Don't tell me this is normal, you can turn that off and all, why can't we have sensible defaults that turns this off by default if this is optional. Say someone new to software engineering is doing this. Compare this with something like `npm install watchman`